# CryptoJS decode return value

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am trying to encode data to Base64 using CryptoJS. My code is as below:

```
let key = "test";
let iv = myCrypto.lib.WordArray.random(16);
let newKey = myCrypto.PBKDF2(key, iv, {keySize: 128/32});
let encrypted = myCrypto.AES.encrypt("hello", newKey, {iv: iv});
let ivString = myCrypto.enc.Base64.stringify(iv);
let decoded = myCrypto.enc.Base64.parse(ivString);
```

When I print decoded, I ma getting the following output:

```
{ init: [Function],
  '$super':
   { init: [Function],
     toString: [Function: toString],
     concat: [Function: concat],
     clamp: [Function: clamp],
     clone: [Function: clone],
     random: [Function: random],
     '$super':
      { extend: [Function: extend],
        create: [Function: create],
        init: [Function: init],
        mixIn: [Function: mixIn],
        clone: [Function: clone] } },
  words: [ -1828772172, 1815131715, 749929333, 1399144403 ],
  sigBytes: 16 }
```

If I try encoding using HEX, I am getting the expected output.

Is this a problem with the CryptoJS library? If not, how do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that when I encode using HEX, I am getting only words, and sigBytes. There are a couple of extra lines when I try encoding using Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Decoded consists of random bytes, which seem to be lazily generated (i.e. when they are required). Just printing the bytes will - by definition - not result in anything useful because the bytes have random values. JavaScript support is a bit tricky because JavaScript doesn't use the byte as primitive type (hence the word array).

To view the bytes first encode them to hexadecimals, and *then* print them.